# how to add multiple layout in single layout Programmatic

Tags: android, layout

how can i add more same layout more then one

```
View v = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag2_layout,container, false);
     RelativeLayout tv = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_layout,container,false);
     RelativeLayout tv2 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_layout,container,false);

    ((LinearLayout) v).addView(tv);
    ((LinearLayout) v).addView(tv);
    ((LinearLayout) v).addView(tv);
    ((LinearLayout) v).addView(tv);
    ((LinearLayout) v).addView(tv);
```

if i do this it give me error and then if i do this it shows it only one time

```
View v = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag2_layout,container, false);
     RelativeLayout tv = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_layout,container,false);
     RelativeLayout tv2 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_layout,container,false);

    ((LinearLayout) v).addView(tv);
    ((LinearLayout) v).addView(tv2);
```

what to do please help

Comment: By the way - your layout is **really** bad, because there is a lot of nested layouts. It's better to move all this stuff into single `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no point in cast:

```
View v = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag2_layout, container, false);
```

Remove cast, or change type of `v` to `LinearLayout`.

It will be better if you'll provide your log cat with error message, but I supose that you're a getting `ClassCastException` here:

```
((LinearLayout) v).addView(tv);
```

Maybe your `v` isn't `LinearLayout`? If you're not sure, try this one instead:

```
((ViewGroup) v).addView(tv);
```

**EDIT**

When you're inflating layout the instance of `View` is created. One `View` can't have more than 1 parent, so when you're doing this:

```
.addView(tv);
.addView(tv);
```

OS thinks that you're trying to add another parent to `tv` (it's prohibited, so it's throws an Exception)

Comment: @nomee.tec use `ListView` instead. If for some reasons you can't, then do same operation in loop (but I strongly recommend you to use `ListView`).

Comment: i cant use ListView Because i m creating sort of Fb comment wall so there will be two lists 1.comment and 2. subcomment

Comment: @nomee.tec you still able to use `ListView`. It may be not scrollable, if you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15960/discussion-between-nomee-tec-and-biovamp)